# Best injection lifetime for WCF client ClientBase<T>

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, soap

I am consuming a SOAP webservice using .NET Connected Service which then generates a client of the type ClientBase. In my Startup.cs file I am injecting the client as Singleton because I have noticed that the first request is somewhat slower than the subsequent requests. However, I am using the client to do many transactions per second more than 50/s. So is it better to inject it as a Scoped service or should I stick to the Singleton lifetime?

Comment: The performance difference between **AddSingleton** and **AddScoped** is usually not significant. For **AddSingleton**, it avoids the overhead of repeated instantiation and destruction.

Comment: If using a singleton ClientBase is thread safe and does not cause problems when called concurrently then it is far better than scoped instance. For me, using Singleton completes in 80 - 100 ms whereas using Scoped takes anywhere between 200 - 800 ms

Comment: **AddSingleton**:It is that only one instance will be used for all requests. So it's faster. The problem is that **AddScopedcan** be used if the speed difference between the individual requests you join is negligible, otherwise **AddSingleton** is better to do so.